# How to get Title of Ringtone with Uri

Tags: android, ringtone

I try this:

```
Uri ringtoneUri = "content://media/internal/audio/media/55";
Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, ringtoneUri);
String name = ringtone.getTitle(context);
```

and I got result: name = 55, not a normal title like "common name"

I also saw [Get the Ringtone title from RingtonePreference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498315/get-the-ringtone-title-from-ringtonepreference)
but there no accepted answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this

```
  Uri ringtoneUri = RingtoneManager
                .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
        Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, ringtoneUri);
        String title = ringtone.getTitle(this);
```

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer. You're using Uri for general ringtone, and the question is asking for a ringtone for a specific contact.